# Ratio and Mensuration of Figures

Tags: contest-math, ratio

[image]

Is there any quick solution to the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Menelaus' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27_theorem) twice, we have
$$\frac{CB}{BD}\times\frac{DP}{PA}\times\frac{AE}{EC}=1\Rightarrow \frac{AE}{EC}=\frac{6}{5}$$
and
$$\frac{CD}{DB}\times\frac{BP}{PE}\times\frac{EA}{AC}=1\Rightarrow BP:PE=11:4$$

**Added** : Another way without using Menelaus' theorem.

Draw a line $DQ$ where $Q$ is on $CA$ such that $DQ$ is parallel to $BE$. Since we have
$$\frac 32=\frac{BD}{DC}=\frac{EQ}{CQ}\ \ \text{and}\ \ \frac 21=\frac{AP}{PD}=\frac{AE}{QE},$$
we have $\frac{AE}{EC}=\frac 65$. Also, draw a line $ER$ where $R$ is on $BC$ such that $ER$ is parallel to $AD$. Since we have
$$\frac{6}{5}=\frac{AE}{EC}=\frac{DR}{CR}\ \ \text{and}\ \ \frac{BP}{PE}=\frac{BD}{DR}\ \ \text{and}\ \ \frac 32=\frac{BD}{DC},$$
we have $\frac{BP}{PE}=\frac{BD}{DR}=\frac{11}{4}$.

Comment: thanks, but is there any way that avoid using strong theorem like Menelaus theorem? Thank you so much.

Comment: @Mayanne: Take a look at the addition.